# Gradle/ivy use cached repos?

Tags: repository, ivy, gradle

I would like Grade/Ivy to use cached versions of my jars, as it takes ~20 seconds to check every time for updates.

Is this possible?

Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the required speed it may be sufficient to setup a local repository proxy (you can do this for multiple repositories not only maven central) with Artifactory or Nexus. This way checking for updates should be much faster since it no longer goes over the internet but only over the local network. Only the first time you use a dependency will the proxy download it from the upstream repository.

Answer (score 1):

Here, as always, is my hack-ey solution:

deps.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d lib ]; then
   rm -rf lib
fi
mkdir lib

cd lib
NAMES=`find ~/.gradle/cache -name \*.jar`
for NAME in $NAMES; do
   ln -s $NAME .
done
```

and my build.gradle becomes

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

/*
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
*/

dependencies {
  /*
  groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.7.0'
  groovy group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.3.2.GA'
  groovy group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: '3.4.0.GA'
  groovy group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.6.0'
  groovy group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt', version: '1.6'
  groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version:     '0.5.0'
  groovy group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit', version: '2.7'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.7'  
  */
  groovy fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: Someone had a better suggestion on gradle-users instead of my deps.sh I can use:

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
  into "lib"
  from configurations.runtime
}

from http://communitymapbuilder.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook

Thank you to
Helmut Dank from gradle users mailing list!